# Wso2 Identity Server Adaptive Authentication with Federation

Tags: wso2-identity-server

We are implementing MFA using Microsoft Azure.  We run wso2 identity server 5.10.4.

What I would like to see happen, is when a user logs in, if they have certain memberOf AD roles, Federation happens.  If not, it just uses basic auth/normal log in.

I've been approaching this problem using Adaptive Authentication custom scripting.  On a service provider, I created two login steps.  Step 1 is basicauth. Step 2 is our MS federated authenticator.

```
var arrayOfRoles = ["employee","student"];
var onLoginRequest = function(context) {
    executeStep(1, {
        onSuccess: function (context) {
            // Extracting authenticated subject from the first step
            var memberOfClaim = 'http://wso2.org/claims/employeeType';
            var user = context.currentKnownSubject;
            var roles = context.currentKnownSubject.localClaims[memberOfClaim];
            foundRole = '-1';
            var arrayOfRolesLen = arrayOfRoles.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfRolesLen; i++) {
                searchRole = roles.indexOf(arrayOfRoles[i]);
                if (searchRole >= 0) {
                    foundRole = searchRole;
                }
            }
            if (foundRole >= 0 ) {
                Log.info(user.username + ' found a role, indexof=' + foundRole);
                // Step 2 is MFA
                executeStep(2);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

The script correctly finds the person's AD memberOf values, and I'm able to execute step 2 using this script.  The problem is that a person logs in once to wso2, then if the roles are matched and exectuteStep(2) is invoked, they are prompted with another log in screen for wso2.

How can I prevent a second log in when a person matches the conditions for step 2?  Or is this the wrong approach to making a role based decision about when to authenticate using basicauth and when to authenticate using federation?

edit:

[image: wso2 auth steps]

Responding to some comments below about using identity-first.

If I setup three steps 1) id first, 2) basic 3) federated, I am prompted for the username again.  Step one, a username prompt from wso2.  Step two, a username and password prompt.  Ditto with step 3.

One difference I see in the below screenshots, is that there is a 'username and password' authenticator.  I don't have that available to me in the drop down boxes.  Just jwt-basic, and basic.   My script using three auth steps looks like this:

````
var arrayOfRoles = ["PCC_EMPLOYEE_ACTIVE","PCC_STUDENT_CREDIT"];

var onLoginRequest = function(context) {
    executeStep(1, {
        onSuccess: function (context) {
            // Extracting authenticated subject from the first step
            var memberOfClaim = 'http://wso2.org/claims/employeeType';
            var user = context.currentKnownSubject;
            var roles = context.currentKnownSubject.localClaims[memberOfClaim];
            
      

            foundRole = '-1';
            var arrayOfRolesLen = arrayOfRoles.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfRolesLen; i++) {
                searchRole = roles.indexOf(arrayOfRoles[i]);
                if (searchRole >= 0) {
                    foundRole = searchRole; 
                }
            }
            
            Log.info('found role is equal to: ' + foundRole);
            
            if (foundRole >= 0 ) {
                Log.info(user.username + ' found a role, indexof=' + foundRole);
                // Step 3 is Azure idp.
                executeStep(3);
            } else {
                // Step 2 is basic auth.
                executeStep(2);
            }
        }
    });
};```
````

Comment: Need more clarification about this the following.
`exectuteStep(2) is invoked, they are prompted with another log in screen`

Did you mean the login screen in the azure side?

Comment: No, when I execute step 2, it shows the wso2 login screen again.

Answer (score 1):

You may try "[identifier First](https://medium.com/@senthalan/identifier-first-login-in-wso2-is-2b4d24316113)" login with [hasRole()](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/references/adaptive-authentication-js-api-reference/#hasroleuser-role) to implement your flow.

i.e.

- Step1 = Identifier
- Step2 = Basic
- Step3 = Azure

Comment: Doing that, the user flow is 1) prompted for their user name by wso2, 2) prompted for the username/pass by wso2, 3) prompted for the username/pass by wso2, then taken to the idp portal.azure.com.   Why does the user have to enter their name twice?   Is there a way to remember the username from the identity-first part, and pass that along to the next steps on behalf of the user?

Comment: ```
    if (foundRole >= 0 )  {
          executeStep(2,{authenticationOptions:[{idp:'portal.azure.com'}]}, {});
       } else {
          executeStep(2,{authenticationOptions:[{authenticator:'basic'}]}, {});
       }
    } ```

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain what you have written here using the script.
So you have two auth steps.

1. Basic auth (username and password)
2. Federated IDP (Azure)

If you have not enabled adaptive script, after the basic auth step (step1), the user needs to authenticate against the FIDP (step2).

According to the current script that you have written, all the users will have a username and password authentication step (step1). Upon the success of that step, FIDP authentication will be enabled (step2) if the user has a certain set of roles.

Now consider a user who has those specified roles. When that user logins, first the user will see the username password login page. After that, the user will see the azure login page if the user has no active session in Azure (If SSO is enabled, the user might not see the second screen). So it is expected to see two login screens.

So what you have done here is correct, but the user experience is kind of weird. A similar scenario is explained [here](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/learn/configuring-role-based-adaptive-authentication/).

Edited: The better approach is to use the identifier first login method. You can read it [here](https://medium.com/@senthalan/identifier-first-login-in-wso2-is-2b4d24316113#:%7E:text=The%20identifier%20first%20in%20the,to%20control%20the%20authentication%20flow.). Please find the approach that I have tried.

I have added 3 steps as follows.
[image: 3 authentication steps]

Next I have added a role based adaptive script.
[image: adaptive auth script]

With this approach if I have the role `admin`, I will only see a input box to provide my password.
[image: password-input]

But for google it will show google sign-in. If you already have a session then only the consent will be seen. We cannot skip this since this is not in our control.

Comment: That seems slightly better.  Although, the user experience is still weird.  They enter their username in step 1 (identifier first), then either step 2 basic, or step 2 idp, requires them to enter their user name a second time.  Is there a way for the user name provided in step 1 to be passed to the step 2 options, so they don't have to enter it twice?

Comment: Sending GET request to URL : https://localhost:9443/api/identity/auth/v1.1/context/xxxxx-9fd5-70cb62d5e315failed. java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://localhost:9443/api/identity/auth/v1.1/context/xxxx486e-409c-9fd5-70cb62d5e315

Comment: @JasonWhitener I have updated my answer. Please check. Please note that I have tried this with IS 6.0.0.

Comment: I don't have a 'username and password' local authenticator.  I just have jwt-basic, and basic.    I'm running wso2 ID 5.10.4.   Other than that difference, I still get prompted twice by wso2 when using identifier-first and basic auth as my first 2 steps.  I edited my post above.